# Many to many on delete set NULL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a many to many relationship between user and group with addtional columns in the join table. It looks like this:

[image]

When I delete an user, it should remove all his references from user_to_group(which works) and all the groups created by him should remain and have their created_by field updated to NULL(this doesn't happen, all the entries are deleted).

DDL for schema:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    username varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    email_address varchar(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    phone_number varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    notification_type varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT "email",
    date_created datetime NOT NULL,
    is_active bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT user_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE `group` (
    group_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(100) NULL,
    date_created datetime NOT NULL,
    is_private bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    created_by int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT group_pk PRIMARY KEY (group_id),
    CONSTRAINT group_user_fk FOREIGN KEY(created_by)
        REFERENCES user (user_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user_to_group (
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    group_id int NOT NULL,
    user_type_id int NOT NULL,
    is_blocked bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT user_to_group_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_id,group_id),
    CONSTRAINT user_to_group_group_fk FOREIGN KEY(group_id)
        REFERENCES `group` (group_id),
    CONSTRAINT user_to_group_user_type_fk FOREIGN KEY(user_type_id)
        REFERENCES user_type (id),
    CONSTRAINT user_to_group_user_fk FOREIGN KEY(user_id)
        REFERENCES user (user_id)
);
```

User Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "username",
            unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email_address",
            unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "notification_type",
    insertable = false)
    private String notificationType = "email";

    @Column(name = "date_created")
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "is_active",
    insertable = false)
    private Boolean active = false;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST},
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<UserGroup> groups;
}
```

Group Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`group`")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "date_created")
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "is_private",
    insertable = false)
    private Boolean privateG = false;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST},
            orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by")
    private User createdBy;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "group",
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST},
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<UserGroup> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

UserGroup(join table):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_to_group")
public class UserGroup {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserGroupId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId("userId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId("groupId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Group group;

    @Column(name = "is_blocked",
    insertable = false)
    private boolean isBlocked = false;
}
```

Ignore user_type_id field on the join table. If I delete an user with on the workbench, it works as expected(created_by field updates to NULL). But if i use this:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User deleteUser(Long id) {

        Optional<User> userToDelete = userRepository.findById(id);

        userToDelete.ifPresent(user -> userRepository.delete(user));

        return userToDelete.orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }
```

the entire row in the group table is deleted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@MapsId("groupId")
@JoinColumn(name = "group_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Group group;
```

exclude `CascadeType.REMOVE` and group will be intact.

Comment: Thank you! It actually worked, but I'm a little confused now. If i modify this, when I delete a group it will delete the reference in the user_to_group table too?

Comment: It wont as you have exluded that in `Group` entity. But this change you made would not affect it anyway.